# Why is NetBeans 8.1 saying multi catch is not supported in -source 1.5 (I have 1.8) when I use a multi catch statement?

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I have Java 1.8 installed on my NetBeans 8 IDE, but whenever I use a multi catch, it throws a compiler error saying that I'm using Java 1.5. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: It looks like your project uses Java 1.5 as the source level, which is the default for maven projects if you do not overwrite it. Specify the source level you want to use, which is most likely 1.8.

Comment: Java 1.5 is the compliance level your project is set to, multi-catch was added in [Java 1.7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java7exceptions-486908.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can fix it by changing the version of your source format.
First you have to open your project **properties** then go to **Sources**. Now you just need to change **Source/Binary Format** to `1.8`